# Sort django query set based on orders in a list

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a django query set like:

```
the_query_set = {<obj1>, <obj2>, <obj3>}
```

and a corresponding list:

```
the_list = [False, True, True]
```

how can I sort `the_query_set` in order of sorted list:

```
the_sorted_list = [True, True, False]
desired_sorted_query_set = {<obj2>, <obj3>, <obj1>}
```

Comment: how it became [True, True, False], shouldn't it be [True, False, False] ?

Comment: you are right it was a typo, I've corrected it. @DavitTovmasyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a solution:

```
[obj for _, obj in sorted(zip(the_list, the_query_set), key=lambda group: group[0])]
```

or

```
[obj for _, obj in sorted(zip(the_list, the_query_set), key=lambda group: group[0], reverse=True)]
```

Comment: it wipes data in queryset @DavitTovmasyan

Comment: actually, I need the_query_set itself after sorting the zipped entity. @DavitTovmasyan